# How to play multiple videos with (player_video) package

Tags: flutter, video-player

I have created this video player for my **application** which can play video from assets. Since, It is made from (**video_player**) package I guess I can play only one video with it But I want **3-4 videos** to be played. How can I do that? It is **possible** or not...Help me! Furthermore, I also want to make the video the option of 10 seconds **backward** and **forward** while pressing it's sides. *Thanks for your* **help**!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(VideoPlay());
}

class VideoPlay extends StatefulWidget {
  String? pathh;

  @override
  _VideoPlayState createState() => _VideoPlayState();

  VideoPlay({
    this.pathh = "assets/video.mp4", // Video from assets folder
  });
}

class _VideoPlayState extends State<VideoPlay> {
  late VideoPlayerController controller;
  late Future<void> futureController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //url to load network
    controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(widget.pathh!);
    futureController = controller.initialize();

    controller.setLooping(true);
    controller.setVolume(25.0);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: futureController,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                      child: VideoPlayer(controller));
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Color(0xff9142db),
            child: Icon(
              controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (controller.value.isPlaying) {
                  controller.pause();
                } else {
                  controller.play();
                }
              });
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

[App Image Is Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngz9L.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]I like your idea and wanted to deal with it, this is the result.
I hope you can do better.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(Example());
}

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.white,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: VideoPlayersList(),
    );
  }
}

class VideoPlayersList extends StatelessWidget {
  const VideoPlayersList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> paths = [
      "assets/images/testvideo.mp4",
      "assets/images/testvideo.mp4",
      "assets/images/testvideo.mp4",
      "assets/images/testvideo.mp4",
      "assets/images/testvideo.mp4",
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: [
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: paths.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return VideoPlay(
                pathh: paths[index],
              );
            },
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VideoPlay extends StatefulWidget {
  String? pathh;

  @override
  _VideoPlayState createState() => _VideoPlayState();

  VideoPlay({
    Key? key,
    this.pathh, // Video from assets folder
  }) : super(key: key);
}

class _VideoPlayState extends State<VideoPlay> {
  ValueNotifier<VideoPlayerValue?> currentPosition = ValueNotifier(null);
  VideoPlayerController? controller;
  late Future<void> futureController;

  initVideo() {
    controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(widget.pathh!);

    futureController = controller!.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initVideo();
    controller!.addListener(() {
      if (controller!.value.isInitialized) {
        currentPosition.value = controller!.value;
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: futureController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive();
        } else {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: controller!.value.size.height,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: controller!.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: Stack(children: [
                    Positioned.fill(
                        child: Container(
                            foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    Colors.black.withOpacity(.7),
                                    Colors.transparent
                                  ],
                                  stops: [
                                    0,
                                    .3
                                  ],
                                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                  end: Alignment.topCenter),
                            ),
                            child: VideoPlayer(controller!))),
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 8,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 3,
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                    onDoubleTap: () async {
                                      Duration? position =
                                          await controller!.position;
                                      setState(() {
                                        controller!.seekTo(Duration(
                                            seconds: position!.inSeconds - 10));
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: const Icon(
                                      Icons.fast_rewind_rounded,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      size: 40,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                    flex: 4,
                                    child: IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        controller!.value.isPlaying
                                            ? Icons.pause
                                            : Icons.play_arrow,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        size: 40,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          if (controller!.value.isPlaying) {
                                            controller!.pause();
                                          } else {
                                            controller!.play();
                                          }
                                        });
                                      },
                                    )),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 3,
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                    onDoubleTap: () async {
                                      Duration? position =
                                          await controller!.position;
                                      setState(() {
                                        controller!.seekTo(Duration(
                                            seconds: position!.inSeconds + 10));
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: const Icon(
                                      Icons.fast_forward_rounded,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      size: 40,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              flex: 2,
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                                    valueListenable: currentPosition,
                                    builder: (context,
                                        VideoPlayerValue? videoPlayerValue, w) {
                                      return Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              videoPlayerValue!.position
                                                  .toString()
                                                  .substring(
                                                      videoPlayerValue.position
                                                              .toString()
                                                              .indexOf(':') +
                                                          1,
                                                      videoPlayerValue.position
                                                          .toString()
                                                          .indexOf('.')),
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  fontSize: 22),
                                            ),
                                            const Spacer(),
                                            Text(
                                              videoPlayerValue.duration
                                                  .toString()
                                                  .substring(
                                                      videoPlayerValue.duration
                                                              .toString()
                                                              .indexOf(':') +
                                                          1,
                                                      videoPlayerValue.duration
                                                          .toString()
                                                          .indexOf('.')),
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  fontSize: 22),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    }),
                              ))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ])),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This will cause memory exceptions while creating multiple video controllers is there any other way to achieve?